# Why does the mirror tool generate inside faces, and how do I fix this?

Tags: faces, normals

I have used and applied a mirror modifier, but when I go into edit mode and select inside faces, the mirrored side is all inside faces. I have selected these and tried shift+N to recalculate normals but it isn't working, the faces are still designated as "inside faces", which as far as I understand it means the normals are pointing inward. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you!

[image: screen shot with inside faces selected]

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of your interface ?

Comment: I added it. Orange selection is inside faces.

Comment: I tried flipping the faces but nothing changed

Comment: I think you confused *inside faces* and *inverted normals*. Please look up these two terms. In your case, you should delete all the *inside faces* and then *recalculate normals* with SHIFT N

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the "interior faces" are forming the shell of my model (they are not inside it) so that if I delete them I get rid of most of one half of the model. You are right, I confused the two terms and thought that Blender must be using normals to determine which faces are "inside" but I guess that is not the case. I am not sure if the "interior faces" is what is causing issues with my mesh in a different program, but maybe it is a different issue

Comment: Do you know if boolean intersections of several pieces might create these interior faces?